# Convert XML key-value pairs to string

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

I have this query:

```sql
SELECT 
    XMLColumn.i.query('.') AS XMLColumn, 
    ID
FROM
    MyTable
CROSS APPLY 
    MyTable.XMLColumn.nodes('Root/Fields') AS Col(i)
```

which returns this result:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦════╗
║        XMLColumn        ║ ID ║
╠═════════════════════════╬════╣
║ <Fields>                ║  1 ║
║   <Field>               ║    ║
║     <Name>First</Name>  ║    ║
║     <Value>1</Value>    ║    ║
║   </Field>              ║    ║
║   <Field>               ║    ║
║     <Name>Second</Name> ║    ║
║     <Value>2</Value>    ║    ║
║   </Field>              ║    ║
║   <Field>               ║    ║
║     <Name>Third</Name>  ║    ║
║     <Value>3</Value>    ║    ║
║   </Field>              ║    ║
║ </Fields>               ║    ║
╚═════════════════════════╩════╝
```

Is there a way to convert this XML structure to the following string format?

```
╔══════════════════════════╦════╗
║        XMLColumn         ║ ID ║
╠══════════════════════════╬════╣
║ First=1;Second=2;Third=3 ║  1 ║
╚══════════════════════════╩════╝
```

Comment: What Rdbms are you using? What version?

Comment: Yes this is possible. But if you want detailed assistance you need to provide some sample data, not the result of another query. Post the ddl for the table. And some sample data as an insert statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pure XQuery approach

```
DECLARE @x XML = 
N'<Fields>
   <Field>
      <Name>First</Name>
      <Value>1</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field>
      <Name>Second</Name>
      <Value>2</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field>
      <Name>Third</Name>
      <Value>3</Value>
   </Field>
</Fields>';
```

-the query

```
SELECT STUFF(
@x.query
('
    for $fld in /Fields/Field
    return <x>{concat(";"
                     ,($fld/Name/text())[1]
                     ,"="
                     ,($fld/Value/text())[1])
               }</x>
').value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'');
```

The idea in short:

We iterate through all the fiels and create an entirely new XML of this format

```
<x>;First=1</x>
<x>;Second=2</x>
<x>;Third=3</x>
```

Using `.value()` with a `.` as XPath will return the entire content (without the tags) as string. `STUFF()` is used to cut away the leading `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the .nodes and .value [XML data type methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/xml-data-type-methods?view=sql-server-2017) to get the element values out of the XML, then use the SQL Server FOR XML trick to concatenate the values into a delimited string. The result of this code includes a trailing delimiter - this may or may not be appropriate for your needs.

```
declare @x xml = '<Fields>
   <Field>
      <Name>First</Name>
      <Value>1</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field>
      <Name>Second</Name>
      <Value>2</Value>
   </Field>
   <Field>
      <Name>Third</Name>
      <Value>3</Value>
   </Field>
</Fields>'

-- Use .nodes and .value methods to get the element values as a rowset.
select
    c.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    c.value('Value[1]', 'int')
from
    @x.nodes('/Fields/Field') as T(c)

-- Use the FOR XML trick to concatenate the values.
select c.value('Name[1]', 'varchar(100)') + '=' + c.value('Value[1]', 'varchar(20)') + ';' AS [text()]
from @x.nodes('/Fields/Field') as T(c)
for xml path ('')
```

Comment: This is okay, +1 from my side, but please allow me some hints:Performance is better, when you use `.value('(Name/text())[1]')` instead of the short version. And - more important - your second query is rather error-prone: If one of the `<Values>` is missing (=> NULL), the whole string will be nulled. And if one of the XML's values might include forbidden characters, you will not get them re-escaped...